# Find value in javascript array by given label

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an ajax jquery function that populates an array with each element containing a label and value:

```
var accountOptions = new Array();
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: apiUrl+"/Accounts/GetDropdown",
        async: false,
        success:
        function (response) {
                $.each(response.Data, function (i, item) {
                    accountOptions.push({ label: item.Number, value: item.Id })
                });
        }
});
```

This function works fine, but I need to find the value (Id) of a given label (account number) by searching for it in the array. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) function, in javascript

```
// options is an array, if you're sure the result is only one use options[0].value, if not you will have to iterate it
var options = accountOptions.filter(function(account) {
    return account.label === 'label-you-are-looking-for';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript array `.filter()` method reduces an array to just the element(s) that meet the given condition in the `return` statement. Try this:

```
var id = accountOptions.filter(function(v) {
    return v.Number == '<Number>';
})
[0].id;
```

```js
var accountOptions = [
    {'Number': '098979','id':98},
    {'Number': '098887','id':99},
    {'Number': '089878','id':97}
];

//get id for Number, '098887'
var id = accountOptions.filter(function(v) {
    return v.Number == '098887';
})
[0].id;

console.log( id );
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to construct a hashtable upon receiving the response:

```
var accountOptions = [];
var accountsById   = {};                                         // added
....
$.each(response.Data, function(i, item) {
    accountOptions.push({ label: item.Number, value: item.Id });
    accountsById[ item.Number ] = item.id;                       // added
});
```

(If multiple results are possible, push to an array instead:

```
    accountsById[ item.Number ] = ( accountsById[ item.Number ] || [] ).push( item.id );
```

)

And fetching the value:

```
var id = accountsById[ label ];
```

*Efficiency*

That is, it is the most efficient in terms of CPU clock cycles and memory access. All other answers so far require one extra pass over the data. For a single lookup, the difference is negligible, but for a second lookup, it is considerable as each lookup requires to iterate all data and perform a string compare on it, whereas using a hashtable is as fast as accessing an object field.

The most efficient solution in terms of maintaining code is the one that requires you to make the least changes, and is often the shortest one; ideally a one-liner.
In terms of dependency management, it is better to use the native `Array.filter` than using a third-party library providing the same functionality that has to be downloaded, parsed, and compiled.

Comment: @Gonzalo Unspecified - OP said *"the value"*. I suspect both id and the account number are unique. If not, `( accountsById[ item.Number ] ||= [] ).push( item.id )` would solve that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$.grep()`

```js
var accountOptions = [{
      label: 123,
      value: "abc"
    }, {
      label: 123,
      value: "def"
    }]
    var id = "abc";

    var res = $.grep(accountOptions, function(item) {
      return item.value === id
    })[0];

    console.log(res.value)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//finds the index of the object you want
function findInArray(theArray, searchFor, property) {
    var retVal = -1;
    var self = theArray;
    for(var index=0; index < self.length; index++){
        var item = self[index];
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (item[property].toLowerCase() === searchFor.toLowerCase()) {
                retVal = index; //or retVal = value if that's what you want
                return retVal;
            }
        }
    };
    return retVal;
};
```

call it like this:

```
findInArray(accountOptions, "whatever label you want", label);
```